# Grouping 0s and 1s in python

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have an array of zeros and ones like `[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]`. How to write a program to save neighboring 0's and 1's in different arrays.

E.g.
`[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]` giving `[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,1]`.

Comment: That's not sorting. Check `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group them with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
>>> data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(group) for item, group in groupby(data)]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1]]
```

The result of `groupby`, will be a tuple of actual item and an iterator which gives the grouped items. We just convert the grouped items to a list, with `list(group)`.

---

As per the comments,

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
>>> flag = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Create a generator which will give the values multiplied,

```
>>> gen = (d * v for d, v in zip(data, flag))
```

Now, group based on the result of calling `bool` on each of the numbers. So, if the `bool` is called on `0`, it will give `False`, otherwise `True`.

```
>>> [list(g) for _, g in groupby(gen, key=bool)]
[[0, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: i have another array [1,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,]. can i multiply the previous answer with this one to get some how [0,0,0],[3,4,5].[0,0,0],[2,3]